# Memory management, objective c

Tags: objective-c, memory-management

Suppose there is a string of type NSSTring

```
      NSString *string;
```

There is array called testArray, which is array of string objects

```
      string=[testArray objectAtIndex:1];
```

Do we need to give

```
      [string release]
```

or not?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, You needn't do

```
[string release]
```

You must `release` object only if you allocate memory for it. Check this [***Memory Management Policy***](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/MemoryMgmt/Articles/mmRules.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000994-BAJHFBGH) for more detail information about alloc and release.

Answer (score 2):

no .. in this case not.

if you get a string from a function, it has usually the autorelease flag and will get released later.

You need to release it if you `retain` it, if you `alloc` it or `copy` it.

You should read: http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/MemoryMgmt/Articles/mmRules.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000994-BAJHFBGH

Answer (score 2):

In this case you do not have to release the string. You only release the Objects which you own (created through alloc/init, copy or retain). Go through the memory management doc by Apple. In this case, testArray owns the string. Hence it takes care of releasing it when no longer required

Answer (score 1):

No need to release. You have to release only the objects that you have allocated.

Answer (score 1):

Only if you also called [string retain].  Otherwise the memory is managed by NSArray.  you might call [string retain] if you need to remove it from the array, but still keep a reference to it.